# what is the best approach to make a dynamic and configurable table in angular 6?

Tags: javascript, html, angular6

Can anyone suggest the best approach to make a dynamic table on a website? I want the table to be configurable.

Comment: Please consider adding a definition and/or an example of what is a dynamic table. Also, what do you mean by configurable?

Comment: configurable means like remove row , col in case if i dont want afterward but this has to done from front end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a table component I wrote

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xdn6nq

To use it you give it an array for the data and a TableConfig object.

```
<app-table [data]="data" [config]="tableConfig"></app-table>
```

A table config object has the interface

```
interface TableConfig {
  columns: ColumnConfig<any>[];
  columnGroups?: ColumnGroup[];
  filters?: ((item: any) => boolean)[];
  groupBy?: GroupBy;
  update?: Subject<boolean>;
}
```

Columns is the main property you will set, it is an array of ColumnConfig which has the interface

```
interface ColumnConfig<T> {
  property: string;
  type?: ColumnType;
  heading?: string;
  sortable?: boolean;
  direction?: ColumnSortDirection;
  compare?: (a: T, b: T) => number; // Return -1 if a is less than b by some ordering criterion, 0 if equal, 1 a is greater than b by the ordering criterion
  display?: (item: T) => string;
  route?: (item: T) => string;
  href?: (item: T) => string;
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean explain those module?

Comment: i mean component mistake, function, loading spin and tables.. in little details

Comment: I deleted loading spinner as it is not needed, table is the component and functions are where I have the functions that group arrays so you can group table rows. Just copy the functions and table folders to somewhere in your project and add the table component to your app module. If the functions and table folders are at different places in your project you will need to update the import statements.

Comment: but i m not hard coding the  data to be print i have using a mock data and i want to display in the table , so what are the modification i need to make.

Comment: Take a look at the app.component in the StackBlitz. You put the mock data in your component.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the primeNG library. The table is a lightning-fast performance  and an excellent level of control over the presentation

This library has well documented and community support on StackOverflow.

[Here is a link of official documentation.](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table)